# What is causing a broken class on re-build of mixed Scala/Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, m2e

I'm working on a mixed Scala/Java project.

I receive this broke class in Eclipse "problem" tab everytime I re-build the Scala code :

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error while loading JsonSerialize$Inclusion, class file 'C:\Users\Adrian\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar(org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize$Inclusion.class)' is broken (class java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException/addChild inapplicable for <none>)   rec-manager     Unknown Scala Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error while loading org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate., class file 'C:\Users\Adrian\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar(org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize$Inclusion.class)' is broken (class java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException/addChild inapplicable for <none>)    rec-manager     Unknown Scala Problem
```

[image]

This issue does not occur when I re-build the Java portion of the code base.

The class does not seem to broken as all is fine when I re-build the Java code.What could be causing this issue ?

If I perform a clean rebuild of the entire project then the issue does not occur.

Comment: This looks like an m2e bug involving Scala and the incremental compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this counts as an answer or a work-around. Perhaps you are using m2e plug-in. And from the screen-shot it seems that the problem is not in the project code, but rather in resolving the dependency library classes / methods ( it refers to .m2 repository ).

Could you try generating an Eclipse project from the command prompt and importing the created project into Eclipse.

Open command prompt and `cd` into the location where `pom.xml` is located.

Now generate the Eclipse project using Maven command line tool. Note that `mvn` should be in your `PATH` variable.

```
C:\> cd Users\Adrian\project1
REM this folder should contains pom.xml 
C:\Users\Adrian\project1> mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

Now import the project into Eclipse

Also I personally never use m2e plugin as it consumes extra resources. Rather, I generate the project using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` or when using SBT, I do `sbt eclipse`.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ive updated to the latest version of Ecliplse (Helios) and Scala plugin and this problem no longer occurs.